# How to update an a postgreSQL unique key constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I keep getting this error within my application

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_supplierinfo_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(409) already exists.

This is on table product_supplierinfo.

The actual next sequence number the key constraint needs to be is 5461 not 409.

Can someone please tell me the correct query to update this key unique constraint?

Comment: Edit your question and include the query.

Comment: I don't know the query that is the question?

Comment: Where is your application getting the `id` value from? Is this an INSERT or an UPDATE? Is that `id` getting its default value from a sequence?

Comment: It is a postgreSQL table called product_supplierinfo and it has a constraint called product_supplierinfo_pkey this number is updated everytime a record is added. HOwever I did a direct import into the database and it threw the constraint counter off.  It thinks the next id number is 409 and it is supposed to be 5461.

Answer (score 0):

@chris Collins, please post the output of `\d product_supplierinfo`.  I imagine you created this table with `id serial`.

You should see the name of the sequence from which the next default value for the id field will come.  It will probably be `product_supplierinfo_id_seq`.

Then do, assuming the above names are correct, `SELECT * from product_supplierinfo_id_seq;`.  You will probably see that the next value is 410.

If this is all correct, do `SELECT setval('product_supplierinfo_id_seq', 5461);`.

Comment: @chris collins, either there are values in the table higher than 5460, or the prinary key index is out of date.  You can check `SELECT max(id) from product_supplierinfo;`.

Comment: How can I fix it if the primary key index is out of date?

Comment: If above gives 5460, try `REINDEX product_supplierinfo;`.  Either way I highly recommend getting to the bottom of why the database is in an inconsistent state.

Comment: I have reindexed not only the table but the whole database.  I also vaccumed the database.  I am still getting the error although now the number is 5469 from repeated attempts.

Comment: Is this happening in a psql session or through a database backed webapp?  In either case it would help to post the query, which I assumed is an INSERT.  You can look in the Postgres log file, unless someone fiddled with the settings you will find the query that caused the error.

Comment: THis issue has now been solved.   I had to reset the value again and now it works.